# Efficiency in for ..next loops of storing array element as variable versus keeping array element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, element

**Question:**
Is it more efficient to store `kmatch(c)` in `e` and use `e`? Please explain why for answers.

**Background:**
While looking for time savings for code to run, the above question came to mind for code below.

**Information on sizes of arrays:**
`kmatch()` stores data from 1 to last row of excel sheet for 1 column. Typically it has a few thousand rows, and `kmatch` and `outputc` are defined earlier in subroutine as variants

**Current code:**

```vb
For c = 1 To UBound(kmatch, 1)
    If kmatch(c) <> 0 Then
        outputc(c, 1) = Abs(Other_array1(kmatch(c), 1))
        outputc(c, 2) = Abs(Other_array2(kmatch(c), 1))
        outputc(c, 3) = Abs(Other_array3(kmatch(c), 1))
        outputc(c, 5) = Other_array4(c, 1)

        If (Abs(Other_array5(kmatch(c), 1)) - Abs(Other_array6(kmatch(c), 1))) > 0 Then
            outputc(c, 4) = Abs(Other_array5(kmatch(c), 1)) - Abs(Other_array6(kmatch(c), 1))
        Else
            outputc(c, 4) = 0
        End If

        For b = 1 To 5
            outputc(c, 6) = outputc(c, b) + outputc(c, 6)
        Next b

        Other_array7(c, 1) = Other_array8(kmatch(c), 1)
    Else
        For b = 1 To 6
            outputc(c, b) = 0
        Next b
    End If
Next c
```

**Planned code:**

```vb
For c = 1 To UBound(kmatch, 1)
    e = kmatch(c)
    If e <> 0 Then
        outputc(c, 1) = Abs(Other_array1(e, 1))
        outputc(c, 2) = Abs(Other_array2(e, 1))
        outputc(c, 3) = Abs(Other_array3(e, 1))
        outputc(c, 5) = Other_array4(c, 1)

        If (Abs(Other_array5(e, 1)) - Abs(Other_array6(e, 1))) > 0 Then
            outputc(c, 4) = Abs(Other_array5(e, 1)) - Abs(Other_array6(e, 1))
        Else
            outputc(c, 4) = 0
        End If

        For b = 1 To 5
            outputc(c, 6) = outputc(c, b) + outputc(c, 6)
        Next b

        Other_array7(c, 1) = Other_array8(e, 1)
    Else
        For b = 1 To 6
            outputc(c, b) = 0
        Next b
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Why don't you just test how long both codes take on your own? I guess there will be no noticeable difference and I would use the second code just because it is easier to read, therefore easier to maintain.

Comment: Given that `kmatch` is integer array, there won't be any noticeable delay in either case. Arrays do not require any lookup, just simple pointer math to calculate element address, from where it can be read just like any scalar variable. VBA however might introduce some bound checks that could delay the process ever so slightly.